# How to save a route in localstorage from vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vue-router

I would like to know how to store in `LocalStorage` a previous route when switching to another route.

I hope to be able to navigate between several routes and not lose the changes made in the previous route.
Also when closing the browser, keep that last route.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last route, but saving the previous state is a lot harder.

You can save the previous route path or name using a guard for [afterEach](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks).

Storing the state is a lot harder and you should probably use something similar to vuex and use **this.$router.go(-1)** yo navigate back.